The problem prevailing when clearing the input form in Material UI when formik.setFieldValue is Used
 <Grid sx={{ pb: 2 }}>
                            <Autocomplete
                                multiple
                                id="tags"
                                options={[]} // Add your options here
                                freeSolo
                                value={formik.values.tags}
                                onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                                    formik.setFieldValue('tags', newValue);
                                }}
                                renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                                    value.map((option, index) => (
                                        <Chip key={index} label={option} onDelete={() => handleDeleteTag(index)} />
                                    ))
                                }
                                renderInput={(params) => (
                                    <TextField
                                        {...params}
                                        label="Tags"
                                        error={formik.touched.tags && Boolean(formik.errors.tags)}
                                        helperText={formik.touched.tags && formik.errors.tags}
                                        value={formik.values.tags}
                                        onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                            if (e.key === ' ') {
                                                // e.preventDefault();
                                                const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
                                                const temp = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim();
                                                if (temp) {
                                                    target.value = '';
                                                    formik.setFieldValue('tags', [...(formik.values.tags ?? []), temp]);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </Grid>

When using the ( react + mui ) and the Autocomplete tag then renderTags to render the tag, the textfield to get the input and the renderInput along with formik the e.target.value='' is not working. But when the formik.setFieldValue is removed e.target.value='' works. I have no idea why this happens.
I tried to create a seprate state variable as tags which is a String Array and then initialize it to the values of the textfield still it didn't work. When I hit space the tag gets added but the current input is there not getting deleted.
Problem which I encounter:
https://i.sstatic.net/JfzS1M72.png
